# home icon on map not loading?

Tags: icons, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have created a map using leaflet.js and have used plugin leaflet.NavBar

https://github.com/davidchouse/Leaflet.NavBar

However, I was able to implement it properly but the home icon is not loading properly. I don't know the reason, maybe because of the icon size. When I inspected, it says size is 26*27. So what could be the size of the icon I should download so as to properly fit in there?

Comment: Make sure you provide enough information for people to be able to reproduce your problem. The [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular about providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) provide some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your css properly. Copy all icons to your project directory before using using it into css

Hope bellow same snippet will help you

```js
var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2013 OpenStreetMap contributors',
    });
    var map = L.map('map').addLayer(osm).setView([39,-77], 10);

    L.control.navbar().addTo(map);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.2/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidchouse.github.io/Leaflet.NavBar/Leaflet.NavBar.css" /> 
<script src="https://davidchouse.github.io/Leaflet.NavBar/Leaflet.NavBar.js"></script>

  <div id="map" style="height:800px;"></div>
```